# How to access the local machine's serial port (USB) data from Heroku application?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, node-serialport

I have a node express application it use `Node-Serialport` library . which is deployed in Heroku cloud platform. When it is running on localhost, then it is working perfectly. When I deploy in Heroku platform, then it is not getting the port data.

It is throwing the below error in Heroku logs,

> 2021-11-03T08:44:28.769675+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/api/v1/port/list" request_id=b1391b01-b640-403f-b0a3-7e389e83bc03 fwd="157.49.66.149" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https 2021-11-03T08:44:28.877150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

Can we possible to solve this problem ?

My code snippet,

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    cors = require('cors');
require("dotenv").config();
const SerialPort = require('serialport');

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));

const server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/port/list', async (req, res) => {
    const list = await SerialPort.list();
    return res.send(list);
})

server.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", function () {
    console.log("Listening on Port 3000");
});
```

It is working on my localhost which reads the local machine port datas.

Answer (score 0):

You Can't Do That™.

When you run your nodejs app on Heroku or any other server, the `serialport` package attempts to access the serial ports *on the server*, not on your local machine. On the sort of virtual machine deployed by Heroku and many other cloud providers, the physical serial ports simply aren't available to software running on the virtual machine.

And, what would you do with the serial port if you could access it?  It's somewhere in a vast rack of servers in some data center.

If you need to access the serial port on a local machine with a web app, you'll need the Web API called [Serial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Serial).  Unfortunately it's only [available](https://caniuse.com/web-serial) on Chromium-based browsers.

Comment: Hi Jones, thanks for your answer. I got an idea that I can use Web serial API instead of using SerialPort. By using Serial API we can get the serial response from the device.